# Does Backtrader and QuantConnect collect any data?

Tags: backtesting, simulations, general

Building an API that integrates with backtrader and QuantConnect to run some backtests. I'm passing in machine generated data and I just want to make sure I'm not sending them too much stuff.

so what data does Backtrader and QuantConnect collect from users?

Comment: [QuantConnect Terms and Conditions](https://www.quantconnect.com/terms)  

[QuantConnect Privacy Policy](https://www.quantconnect.com/privacy)